# golang mux, routing wildcard & custom func match

Tags: go, mux

I'm using the [mux](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux) package which seems to work quite well except that it doesn't seem to support complex routes or at least I don't get it how it does. 
I have several routes as following:

```
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.HandleFunc("/{productid}/{code}", product)
router.HandleFunc("/{user}", userHome)
router.HandleFunc("/search/price", searchPage)
```

So I  have two questions:

- How can I define a wildcard route such  /search/price/*  so that a request such  /search/price/29923/rage/200/color=red  can match it ?
- Is it possible to add custom  conditions to an existing route ? e.g. if the route is `/{productid}/{code}` and function x  returns `true` , use this `handlerTrue`, if it returns `false` use `handlerFalse`.

I've tried to add something like  `.MatcherFunc(myfunction(ip)bool)` to the route  but it complains that the router has no such method.

Currently  I'm handling the 'custom' conditions inside the handler.

Comment: The title should probably mention that it's gorilla mux, because there is mux in the go stdlib, so the title is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 12):

You can use regexps. Something like

```
router.HandleFunc(`/search/price/{rest:[a-zA-Z0-9=\-\/]+}`, searchPage)
```

That way, `rest` will just capture everything, so in your example `rest` would be `29923/rage/200/color=red`. You will need to parse that in your code.

You probably want some like optional arguments, though.

```
router.HandleFunc(`/search{price:(\/price\/[0-9]+)?}{rage:(\/rage\/[0-9]+)?}{color:(\/color=[a-z]+)?}`, searchPage)
```

After that, you get vars `price = "/price/29923"`, `rage = "/rage/200"` and `color = "/color=red"`, that you still need to parse, but its easier, and you get to control which parameters are valid. It works as expected if you skip some parameter, eg. `/search/price/29923/color=red` will just give an empty `rage` variable, but still match.

I don't quite get your second question.

Comment: Sorry. For the second solution, which involves subexpressions, I think you'd need this fork of mux: https://github.com/gorilla/mux/pull/11 which is what I used in my last project.

Comment: the regex throws an error: "unknown escape sequence"

Comment: Yeah, "" should be ``. Edited.

Comment: It doesn't throw out the error but the route is not handled either (I get 404 ) e.g. /search/price/0.000/asdasd/asdasd

Comment: The dot isn't matched, your initial example had no dot. Add it to the pattern: [a-zA-Z0-9=\-\/\.]+

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure you need a "wildcard" route at all: you just need a route with multiple parameters:

`/search/price/{price}/rage/{id}/color` will work, noting that query strings don't need to be included in the matcher (you access those via `request.URL.Query`, whereas you access the mux variables via `mux.Vars`. You can also use regex to narrow down the accepted parameters.

It will also help to differentiate your user and product routes, perhaps by prefixing them with `/user/{id}` and `/products/{id}/{code}` (particularly for semantics).

As far as `MatcherFunc` goes, you need to make sure your function uses the same signature as MatcherFunc (which is a type): `func MatchIPAddresses(*http.Request, *RouteMatch) bool` would solve it. You can access the IP address via the [Request](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) struct by checking `r.RemoteAddr` or `r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For")` if you expect to be behind a proxy. I typically check both if one is empty (`""`).

i.e. (rough; you can clean this up a bit!)

```
func MatchIPAddresses(r *http.Request, rm *RouteMatch) bool {
    if r.RemoteAddr == 8.8.8.8 {
        return true
    } else if r.Header.Get("X-Forwarded-For") == 8.8.8.8 {
        return true
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: undefined: RouteMatch, cannot use myfunction(<T>, *RouteMatch) (type bool) as type mux.MatcherFunc in function argument

Comment: I've fixed my example. I also highly recommend reading the Gorilla Mux docs, which have a similar example of how to write a MatcherFunc about halfway down the page: http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux

Comment: I've read the docs before to post the question. I think your answer is basically copied from the docs except the ip function.

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom MatcherFunc with gorilla mux, you need to ensure that your matcher is actually of type mux.MatcherFunc. This is because MatcheFunc is not an interface type

```go
// From mux/route.go line 303
// MatcherFunc is the function signature used by custom matchers.
type MatcherFunc func(*http.Request, *RouteMatch) bool
```

So you have to do something like:

```go
var myMatcher mux.MatcherFunc = func(request *http.Request, match *mux.RouteMatch) bool {
  // Your custom logic
  return trueOrFalse
}

// You can then use it on your route like this.
router := mux.NewRouter()
router.HandleFunc("/{productid}/{code}", product).MatcherFunc(myMatcher)
```

Answer (score -1):

With chi as router you can do the following:

Since the regex never matches a slash `/` you can simply match with `*`

e.g. for `/search/price/29923/rage/200/color=red`

```
router.Get(`/search/price/*`, priceHandler)

func DashboardFilesHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    path := myhandler.UrlParam(r, "*")
    // path will be '29923/rage/200/color=red'
}
```

See also: https://godoc.org/github.com/go-chi/chi

> A placeholder with a name followed by a colon allows a regular
>   expression match, for example {number:\d+}. The regular expression
>   syntax is Go's normal regexp RE2 syntax, except that regular
>   expressions including { or } are not supported, and **/ will never be**
>   **matched.** An anonymous regexp pattern is allowed, using an empty string
>   before the colon in the placeholder, such as {:\d+}
>
> The special placeholder of **asterisk matches the rest of the requested**
>   **URL.** Any trailing characters in the pattern are ignored. This is the
>   only placeholder which will match / characters.